# How to print all of the elements in a list

Tags: list, printing, python-3.x, element

I need to be able to print all of the elements in a randomly chosen list without the brackets or commas. I tried to print each element with the '+' operator but it raised an error about not being able to convert the list to a string. Here is my code now:

```
t1 = ["rock", 80, 1,2,1]
t2 = ["carpet", 75, 2, 2, 1]
t3 = ["lava", 1000, 1, 1, 1]
t4 = ["rock", 90, 2, 1, 1]
Tiles = [t1, t2, t3, t4]
print(random.choice(Tiles)[0] + [1] + [2] + [3] + [4])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `print` function can take multiple arguments. You don't want to try to stick everything together, because they're of different types - just let Python print them out in order.

```
title = random.choice(Titles)
print(title[0], title[1], title[2], title[3], title[4])
```

Of course, that's a bit unwieldy, and doesn't really reflect the intent. Fortunately, there is a shortcut that lets us feed all the items of a list as parameters to a function:

```
title = random.choice(Titles)
print(*title)
```

Or, since we don't really need that name any more, just:

```
print(*random.choice(Titles))
```

Comment: Well I wanted to try and do it one line. Your method works fine also and it is by far the easiest so I will probably change my program to use your method. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably closer to what you want, I think:

```
print ' '.join(map(unicode, random.choice(Tiles)))
```

Comment: That raised other errors relating to strings and integers conflicting.

Comment: @Zizma - you can coerce the values if you want to ... I'll modify the answer a bit.

Comment: `' '.join(str(x) for x in random.choice(Tiles))`

Comment: @g.d.d.c That works on Python 2.x but not 3.x which is what I'm using. :(

Comment: @Zizma - Sorry, I default to 2.x syntax - we haven't transitioned to 3.x internally.  Sounds like you're good to go now though. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should save the result of random choice in a variable, then iterate over its members and print in order.

Comment: That would work but do you know of a way to do it all in one line?

Comment: Why bother making it one line?

Comment: I guess I don't need to. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import random
>>> t1 = ["rock", 80, 1,2,1]
>>> t2 = ["carpet", 75, 2, 2, 1]
>>> t3 = ["lava", 1000, 1, 1, 1]
>>> t4 = ["rock", 90, 2, 1, 1]
>>> Tiles = [t1, t2, t3, t4]
>>> print(random.choice(Titles)[0])
"rock"
```

Comment: That's not at all like what I said that I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a bunch of elements of different types and want to print them. What you should do is make a string of the data you want and print that.

Something like this:

```
>>> import random
>>> tiles = [
...     ["rock", 80, 1,2,1],
...     ["carpet", 75, 2, 2, 1],
...     ["lava", 1000, 1, 1, 1],
...     ["rock", 90, 2, 1, 1],
... ]
>>> tile = random.choice(tiles)
>>> print("The random tile is '{0}', with the values {1}, {2}, {3} and {4}".format(*tile))
The random tile is 'rock', with the values 80, 1, 2 and 1
```

Anything else is pretty much only suitable for debugging. Like:

```
>>> print(*tile)
rock 80 1 2 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print(repr(random.choice(Tiles))[1:-1].replace(',','  '))
```

Comment: I would really like to understand what is deserving a downvote in my answer. What's the problem in my answer ??

Comment: Karl Knechtel's answer is better than mine because it perfectly resort to the fact that print() is a function in Python 3. I should have think to this solution , even if I can't test in Python 3 that I have not installed. However, my answer isn't wrong, I think, and I find downvoting it without any explanation is rather weird